# Module parse fail: Babel parsing js module in React Project

Tags: reactjs, parsing, webpack, babeljs

I'm building my first semi-major MERN app with Redux, without a tutorial.  It's really challenging, but a ton of fun.

The project I am building is, essentially, a simple re-engineering of Zillow's API (they have a few, I'm after the more basic of the property search results).

I am using the zillow npm module and want to add what appears to be a pretty popular autocomplete Search plug-in.

My big challenge this week has been diving into the build tools.  I read thru the webpack docs over the last couple days, then felt solid enough to try building out my Search functionality, which will return results and a map eventually.

It should be noted, I'm using a scaffolding tool developed by a guy who publishes a lot of good React tutorials (from which I basically learned ReactJS -- it's called turbo360).  Right now, I am using webpack 4.  I just did a fresh git commit:  https://github.com/ScorpIan555/real-estate-app/blob/master/webpack.config.js

I have, so far, read a bit of the Babel docs.  I piped in .js extentions to the .jsx test for the babel-loader, thinking perhaps that would get it?

What I'm a bit confused by is that it seems to be tripping over a file written in ES5 (from the geocoder npm module I am trying to use).  So, I'm wondering if I should be configuring my babel-loader to not try to transpile ES5 modules or what.

This is the module I am trying to utilize, it looks fairly popular and has a recent commit.  I also looked at its webpack.config.js file and tried to apply that to mine...

https://github.com/abec/react-autosuggest-geocoder/blob/master/webpack.config.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this as I received assistance on a Slack channel.  This plugin uses experimental code which I do not wish to use on my app.  I will use another plug-in.  I was looking for help with my webpack.config and am reliably told it is fine.  Thanks to all who viewed this question!